# An integration result

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int ^{a}_{0} f(x) dx = \int ^{a}_{0} f(a-x) dx, a > 0$$

I'm having a problem understanding this formula.

I know that it is essentially a substitution but how?

How does this formula work.

Please explain,  with examples. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $u = a - x$ in the second integral. Then

$$du = d(a - x) = 0 - dx = -dx$$

If $x = 0$, then $u = a$; if $x = a$, then $u = 0$. Hence the integral can be written as

$$\int_0^a f(a - x) dx = \int_a^0 f(u) (-du) = \int_0^a f(u) du$$

In the last equality, we've used the fact that

$$\int_a^b f(x) dx = - \int_b^a f(x) dx$$

Comment: I'm lost on your second line, where did you get 0 - dx from?

Comment: @Aaron The derivative of a constant is $0$, so $da = 0$.

Comment: Oh ok thanks. Does this particular type of substitution have a specific name (theorem-wise)?

Comment: @Aaron It's usually called "change-of-variables."

Comment: A more "graphic" way to see it is that in the first expression, you sum your function from 0 to a, and on the right one, you sum it from a to 0, by making the quantity (a-x). But there is no minus sign, because your x quantity increases.